# Vim Starts on Insert Mode and Inserts Special Characters

Tags: linux, vim

So vim just suddenly started flaking out on me today and I can't pinpont the problem. Haven't touch the configuration file and the last thing I worked on before I noticed the problem was updating my sshd_config and sshd_config.pacnew files.

What I noticed is that upon opening the sshd_config file is vim starting out in insert mode and automatically inserted a series special characters wherever the curser was at the moment. So it overwrites information in configuration files. I guess that can become somewhat problematic =)

So if I start a new file `touch test_vim && vim test_vim` this is what I see:
`:bfff/00fe/00fe/13fe[>85;95;0c`

I have a feeling this is going to be one of those things that's really stupid and I completely overlooked. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2014 Feb 05
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file (restore to previous version)
  set undofile      " keep an undo file (undo changes after closing)
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif
```

Comment: Are you sure that file `test_vim` doesn't exist before you did a `touch` on it ?

Comment: I'm sure. I created several test files to confirm. Or I can open any existing file and vim will just add those special characters to that file.

Comment: so, what happens if you don't source your .vimrc?

Comment: the problem goes away if I don't source my vimrc.. I haven't touched my vimrc file since setting up vim. Any idea what's going on here? Just a thought, but I can try using the vimrc file from my other notebook to see if that does anything they use the same configuration.

Comment: Post your vimrc. Do you have any mappings to escape (`<esc>`) in it?

Comment: I don't have any mappings to escape. Alright, posted .vimrc

Comment: Okay, so searching online I stumbled onto vim registers, something which I knew nothing about. .viminfo stores these registers, so I looked in the file and sure enough the second register in the list contains those special characters. Don't know how they got in there. I must have accidentally hit the wrong series of keys at some point. I also noticed my email address and some shell commands in other registers, apparently you can have more than one. They just store information for later use. I must be inadvertently adding them in. Could this be the problem? Still doesn't explain insert mode.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `vim`, try `alias | grep vim`.

Comment: Same thing happens. Someone mentioned it being a bug, but it doesn't seem to affect my other computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a recent Vim bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/LLGjKaEzNUY). You should probably roll back to an earlier release while a proper fix is worked on.

Comment: Hmm... that's odd because it's not affecting my other computer which uses the same version of vim. Thanks for the heads up, guess it's back to nano for now

Comment: The bug seems to affect urxvt termianls and may be realted to transparency. Works find when using other terminals.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look about changing the vim configuration files on this post
this is the official vim wiki page

[Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems)

Comment: I haven't laid a hand on the configuration file so I think it's some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the bug seems to affect urxvt terminals running with transparency. Using a different terminal, or in my case disabling transparency via /.Xresources will temporarily solve the issue until they release a patch.